# How to get a file in flask by sending fetch

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch

I have a flask API. Using Postman everything works well, but when I try to send a file via `fetch` it doesn't come up.

### print(request.files)

```
ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

### flask

```
@app.route('/voice_to_text',  methods=['POST'])
def api_voice_to_text():
    try:
        check_model(model_dir)
        audio = request.files.get('audio')
        print(request.files)
        filename = f'{audio.filename}_{random.randint(0, 100000)}.wav'
        audio.save(os.path.join("audio", filename))
        return jsonify({"result": transcript}), 200
    except:
        return jsonify({"result": "error"}), 400
```

### html and js

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "Utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<input id="audio-file" type="file" />
</body>
<script>
let audio = document.getElementById("audio-file").files[0];
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("audio", audio);
setTimeout(testSizze, 5000);
async function testSizze(){
const res = await fetch("http://0.0.0.0:5000/voice_to_text", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
});
const json = await res.json();
    console.log(json)
}   
</script>
</html>
```